# Порядок байт IP адресов в sk_buff

Tags: linux, сеть, системное-программирование

Всегда ли в заголовке сетевого уровня (например, в IPv4 заголовке), указатель на который можно получить с помощью `ip_hdr(const struct sk_buff *)`, адреса хранятся в сетевом порядке байт?

Comment: какие именно адреса? https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/networking/API-struct-sk-buff.html

Comment: @KoVadim, IP адреса в заголовке сетевого уровня (например, в IPv4 заголовке) sk_buff.network_header

Comment: network header - это 2 байта. адреса там нет - ipv4 там не влезет

Comment: @KoVadim, [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023226/what-do-the-sk-buff-functions-skb-network-header-and-skb-mac-header-do) - ну или по смещению `sk_buff.network_header`, неважно. Суть в том, что IP адреса  в том или ином виде там содержатся

Comment: ох. перечитайте свой вопрос и то, что пишется в последнем комментарии. В любом случае, если это именно ipv4 заголовок, то там должно быть в сетевом порядке.

Comment: @KoVadim, я внес правки в свой вопрос, надеюсь, теперь там нет противоречий. Спасибо

Comment: если посмотреть в реализацию https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/ip.h#L19 и https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/ip.h#L86 то стает очевидным, что содержимое буффера кастится на структуру, а переменные структуры имеют тип  be16/be32, что как бы намекает.

Comment: А причём тут Linux? Это определено спецификациями на IP протокол.